# SQL query to show only active jobs, not the expired jobs

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query to display jobs that are not yet expired. I also want to show the jobs that are expiring today.

```
SELECT jd.`job_title`,jd.`date_expiry`,jc.`category_title`
FROM `job_details` AS jd
JOIN `job_category` AS jc
ON jc.`category_id`=jd.`category_id`
WHERE jd.`company_id`=2
AND jd.`date_expiry` >= NOW()
ORDER BY jd.`date_expiry` ASC
```

The query works fine for jobs that are expired yesterday or before, but it does not show jobs that are expiring today. Jobs that are expiring today are supposed to be shown to users. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your query is that `NOW()` returns a timestamp at this exact moment in time, which could be in the middle of the day, the beginning, or the end.  If `NOW()` were in the middle of the day, then anything expiring *before* that point would be excluded from your query.  One workaround would be to compare to the current date at midnight.

You can use `TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)` to achieve this, and [read here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152585/getting-midnight-of-today) for a very helpful DBA Stack Exchange question.

```
SELECT
    jd.job_title,
    jd.date_expiry,
    jc.category_title
FROM job_details AS jd
INNER JOIN job_category AS jc
    ON jc.category_id = jd.category_id
WHERE jd.company_id = 2 AND
      jd.date_expiry >= TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)   -- compare to today at midnight
ORDER BY jd.date_expiry
```